# javascript is not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I have used a fb script to increase a size of canvas. Here is the code..

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '171963559525911', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 1500, height: 1500 });
    };

    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is working in all browsers I've tested except IE8. In fact also working in IE9 but not working in IE8.

Please suggest me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you want any help, you're going to have to say what exactly isn't working. Is ie8 throwing an error? What is it? On what line? etc.

Comment: What is "all browser"? Firefox? Chrome? Safari? Opera? IE7? IE6? IE5?!

Comment: It is working in all browser.only IE8 & IE7

Comment: What isn't working? What errors do you get?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined 
?code=dJiyVLy7chjqxpHRPjsfRy_CESxQCbvvBYLP795Dd8E.eyJpdiI6Imo4LUttdElNVE5ZUy1Ba0FJbkt1dHcifQ.5k-7v8CXu0QS8DXty5wEYLqkJ4TrlkWFmLGtpGzch-ZXFTgQCleviEeAY9JCJAtR17mm2l-bzPYzSORmPiPmX57o4MiYE05juHgvFSoUDhhsXfZEJZClJysMQsyXgIkC, line 44 character 9
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught 
activatables.js, line 193 character 12

Comment: Your script tag for JQuery isn't closed properly `</script` -- missing the final `>`. Not sure if that's a copy+paste error in the question or if it's actually a problem in your code?

Comment: Its copy paste issue.It is closed in my scipt

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to append the script to the `fb-root` div?  Have you tried appending the script to the body?  `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(e)`

Comment: Your example code looks ok to me in ie8 (http://jsfiddle.net/bWhyc/), something else may be causing the problem. I notice that your error message is being thrown by "activetables.js", which is nowhere in your sample code. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Do you place it into `head` or `body`?

Comment: I would change `if (!e) throw 'Could not find "' + item + '".'
   path.push(e);`
to `if (!e) alert('Could not find "' + item + '".'); return;
   path.push(e);` also it says: `It is recommended that this file is included before the </body> tag to ensure` so did you?

Comment: It run in [all browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers)?

Comment: BTW, I hope that's not your __real__ app id in the code.

Comment: Thanks guys.I finally solved the issue.It fixed by @Chris Barretto answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use for extending the size of my canvas and it works in all browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"], function()
    {
      FB.XdComm.Server.init("/xd_receiver.htm?v=2");
      FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
    });
    function onWindowResized(info)
    {
      var canvasInfoDiv = document.getElementById("CanvasInfo");
      var text = String.format("window ({0}, {1}), page ({2}, {3}), canvas({4}, {5}), scrollPos({6}, {7}), canvasPos({8}, {9})", 
        info.window.w, info.window.h,info.page.w, info.page.h,
        info.canvas.w, info.canvas.h,
        info.scrollPos.x, info.scrollPos.y,
        info.canvasPos.x, info.canvasPos.y);
      canvasInfoDiv.innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
```

You need to have the xd_receiver.htm inside of a publicly accessibly directory as well. Here is the contents of that file:

xd_receiver.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>cross domain receiver page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  FB.init({appId:'your-app-id', status:true, cookie:true, xfbml:true});
  $(window).load(function(){
    FB.Canvas.setSize({height:1100});
  });
});
```

Obviously set the height to whatever the height of your content is. Before I had:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({height:$('html').height()});
```

But IE seems to not like that. Shouldn't have to explicitly set the height #, but had to in this case.

Comment: Thanks its working in IE 8 & 9 but not working in mozila & crome.

Comment: Don't know if this comment is still valid, but with Facebook's constantly changing code, this is what I am using now which works across all browsers (below)

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this one:

```
$.ajax({

  url: document.location.protocol +'/connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js',

  dataType: 'script',

  success: function(){//do anything ...}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
        //doing stuff
    } ());
```

should be

```
(function () {
        //doing stuff
    })();
```

Comment: Actually, they're essentially the same.  The goal of the parens is to ensure the function is parsed as an expression, rather than a declaration - both approaches achieve that.

Comment: thanks for the correction. still, i wouldnt be surprised if that was something some browsers got wrong.